# How to iterate over all textarea elements inside a div

Tags: javascript, html

I want to retrieve the content of all `textarea` elements inside a particular div. Here is how I tried to iterate over them

```
var ta = document.getElementById('parent').getElementsByTagName('textarea')
ta.forEach(element => {
  console.log(element);
});
```

but I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: ta.forEach is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (details:512)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

Is this the proper way to get all `textarea` elements inside a particular div?
I want to get the content of all of these `textarea` elements along with the name of the element. How can I do that?

Comment: `.getElementsByTagName('textarea')` returns nothing.

Comment: oh right, how can i get the textarea elements inside that div ?

Comment: Can we see the markup?

Comment: If the `<textarea>`s are indeed contained in a common parent with `id="parent"`, you could use `[...document.querySelectorAll('#parent textarea')].forEach(el => { console.log(el)})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). It does not have the `forEach` method. Use the `for` loop as illsutrated in [Element.getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName).

```
var ta = document.getElementById('parent').getElementsByTagName('textarea');
for (let element of ta) {
  console.log(element);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, [but don't use `.getElementsByTagName()` at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), which allows for any valid CSS selector to be passed to it and it will return a collection of all matching elements. Then, loop over the results, but because [IE doesn't support `.forEach()` on collections](https://caniuse.com/#search=forEach), you should convert it into a formal array before using `.forEach()`.

And [don't use `.getElementsByTagName()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474) (ever again).

```js
// Get the textareas inside the div with an id of "target2"
let areas = document.querySelectorAll("#target2 textarea");

// Convert the collection into an array and loop over the array
Array.prototype.slice.call(areas).forEach(function(area){
  console.log(area.textContent);
});
```

```html
<div id="target">
  <textarea>stuff</textarea>
</div>
<div id="target2">
  <textarea>stuff2</textarea>
  <textarea>stuff2a</textarea>
</div>
<div id="target3">
  <textarea>stuff3</textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to get the content of the input or textarea, I think you could use .value to capture that and print it to console.

something like:

```
for (i = 0; i < document.getElementById('parent').getElementsByTagName('textarea').length; i++) {
  console.log(document.getElementById('parent').getElementsByTagName('textarea')[i].value)
}
```

editing since it HTML collection in fact does not work with .value

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns an `HTMLCollection`, which does not have a `value` property.

Answer (score -1):

You want something like this?(Write text and click outside)

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].onchange = function(){ console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value);
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```